# geom_ribbon different colours - R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

I am using the following code to plot my data but I cannot manage to set the colours to geom_ribbon properly.

My graph contains 4 lines, each of one with a different color. I want the 'geom_ribbon' of each line to have the same color as its line (with transparency - alpha).

In addition, when I change the value of alpha (e.g. from 0.1 to 0.9) I dont't see any change on the transparency. Finally, an extra class is added in the legend and I would like to remove this? Any help on this basic ggplot?

```
ggplot(dfmean_forplot, aes(x = image, y = value, group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(ID)))+ 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:21,
  labels=c("19/1","7/2","17/2","18/3","17/4","27/4","17/5","27/5","7/6","16/6","26/6","5/7","16/7","6/8","15/8","25/8","4/9","25/9","4/10","14/10","22/11"))+ 
  xlab("# reference")+
  ylab("value")+
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "class")+
  ylim(0,0.9)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=dfmean_forplot$value-dfsd_forplot$value, ymax=dfmean_forplot$value+dfsd_forplot$value, alpha = 0.3))
```

[image]

#### EDIT

What about the legend? Ideally, I would like to combine them so that there is a square for each color crossed by a line of the same color
[image]
[image]

Comment: Give the same name to both scales, and they should be joined

Comment: Totally right! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `fill` aesthetic and take `alpha` outside `aes`, both for `geom_ribbon`. The following code should solve that.

```
ggplot(dfmean_forplot, aes(x = image, y = value, group = ID)) + 
 geom_line(aes(colour=factor(ID)))+ 
 scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:21,
                  labels=c("19/1","7/2","17/2","18/3","17/4","27/4","17/5","27/5","7/6","16/6","26/6","5/7","16/7","6/8","15/8","25/8","4/9","25/9","4/10","14/10","22/11"))+
 xlab("# reference")+
 ylab("value")+
 scale_colour_discrete(name = "class")+
 ylim(0,0.9)+
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=dfmean_forplot$value-dfsd_forplot$value, 
                 ymax=dfmean_forplot$value+dfsd_forplot$value,
                 fill = factor(ID)), alpha = 0.3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works properly. I have edited the question to show the result and ask you a doubt about the legend. + could you explain what is the difference of having the parameters inside `aes` or outside?

Comment: Inside the `aes` you are _mapping_ to a variable. That means that `aes(alpha = 0.3)` makes ggplot think that there is some variable with the value 0.3 that needs to be assigned an alpha value. It is being helpful by creating a legend, showing you what alpha value is mapped to this new variable. Outside `aes`, you are _setting_ it to a constant. That means that there is no interpretation by ggplot that makes up a scale, but it just gives it a value of 0.3, and there is no legend given.